# Explorer error after windows 8.1 update 1

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, debug

I'm getting explorer crash and in the eventviewer the cause seems to be the kernelbase.dll. I've the dump. If someone could debug it for me i would appreciate. Best regards

https://gsdid6.s.cld.pt

Answer (score 1):

You get a well known crash, caused by Autodesk Inventor (`rse.dll`):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for utx.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for rse.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for DtBridge.dll - 

FAULTING_IP: 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68
00007ffe`d7c08b9c 488b8c24c0000000 mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffed7c08b9c (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000068)
   ExceptionCode: e06d7363 (C++ EH exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 4
   Parameter[0]: 0000000019930520
   Parameter[1]: 000000000859b510
   Parameter[2]: 00007ffebd92db30
   Parameter[3]: 00007ffebd7c0000
unable to find C-Runtime symbols, even with unqualified search

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
rax=0000000009d40000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000009d40000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=00007ffeda73138a rsp=0000000008599d58 rbp=000000000859ad80
 r8=0000000000001000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000040
r11=0000000000000286 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000009d30000
r14=ffffffffffffffff r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe cy
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000203
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00007ffe`da73138a c3              ret

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe06d7363 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe06d7363 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000019930520

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000000859b510

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00007ffebd92db30

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER4: 7ffebd7c0000

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

APP:  explorer.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000514

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_APPLICATION_FAULT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000063ab14f1 to 00007ffed7c08b9c

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
ntdll!RtlReportExceptionEx
ntdll!RtlReportException
ntdll!LdrpCalloutExceptionFilter
ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode$filt$1
ntdll!_C_specific_handler
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!RtlRaiseException
KERNELBASE!RaiseException
msvcr100!CxxThrowException
utx!UTxException::IsFatal
utx!UTxThrower::operator()
rse!RSeTxnBulletin::SetDefunct
rse!RSeTest::IsRSeMemory
rse!RSeTest::IsRSeMemory
rse!RSe::DebugOnly_AssertIsNotInRSeTransactedSegment
rse!RSe::CreateTransactingTransientSegment
rse!UTxDiagnosis::PostDiagnosis
rse!UTxDiagnosis::PostDiagnosis
rse!std::_Mutex::_Mutex
verifier!AVrfpStandardDllEntryPointRoutine
ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine
ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode
ntdll!LdrpInitializeGraph
ntdll!LdrpInitializeGraph
ntdll!LdrpInitializeGraph
ntdll!LdrpInitializeGraph
ntdll!LdrpPrepareModuleForExecution
ntdll!LdrpLoadDll
ntdll!LdrLoadDll
verifier!AVrfpLdrLoadDll
KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW
DtBridge!DTxInfoTipBridge::GetCurFile
DtBridge!DTxShellExtBridge::operator=
DtBridge!DTxShellExtBridge::DTxShellExtBridge
DtBridge!DTxShellExtBridge::DTxShellExtBridge
combase!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance
combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
combase!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance
combase!CProcessActivator::CCICallback
combase!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation
combase!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext
combase!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance
combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
combase!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance
combase!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
combase!ICoCreateInstanceEx
combase!CComActivator::DoCreateInstance
combase!CoCreateInstanceEx
combase!CoCreateInstance
shell32!_SHCoCreateInstance
shell32!SHExtCoCreateInstance
shell32!DCA_SHExtCoCreateInstance
shell32!HDXA_QueryContextMenu
shell32!CDefFolderMenu::QueryContextMenu
shell32!CExecuteItem::Execute
shell32!COpenThisPcOrLibrariesCommand::Execute
shell32!CBindAndInvokeStaticVerb::_DoCommand
shell32!CBindAndInvokeStaticVerb::_TryExecuteCommandHandler
shell32!CBindAndInvokeStaticVerb::Execute
shell32!CRegDataDrivenCommand::_TryInvokeAssociation
shell32!CRegDataDrivenCommand::_Invoke
shell32!CRegistryVerbsContextMenu::_Execute
shell32!CRegistryVerbsContextMenu::InvokeCommand
shell32!`Microsoft::WRL::Module<1,Microsoft::WRL::Details::DefaultModule<5> >::Create'::`2'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'module''
shell32!CDefFolderMenu::InvokeCommand
shell32!CShellExecute::_InvokeInProcExec
shell32!CShellExecute::_InvokeCtxMenu
shell32!CShellExecute::_DoExecute
shell32!CRegFolder::_FlushCache
SHCore!StrRetToBSTR
verifier!AVrfpStandardThreadFunction
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart




SYMBOL_NAME:  rse!RSeTxnBulletin::SetDefunct+189c

IMAGE_NAME:  rse.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  512fd389

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_e06d7363_rse.dll!RSeTxnBulletin::SetDefunct


    Loaded symbol image file: rse.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Inventor 2014\Bin\rse.dll
    Image name: rse.dll
    Timestamp:        Thu Feb 28 23:00:41 2013 (512FD389)
    CheckSum:         002B8E46
    ImageSize:        002B6000
    File version:     18.0.17000.0
    Product version:  1.0.0.1
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Autodesk, Inc.
    ProductName:      Autodesk, Inc. rse
    InternalName:     rse
    OriginalFilename: rse.dll
    ProductVersion:   Autodesk Inventor 2014
    FileVersion:      18, 0, 17000, 0000
    PrivateBuild:     Build: 170, Release: 2014 RTM - Date: Thu 02/28/2013       
    SpecialBuild:     Build: 170, Release: 2014 RTM - Date: Thu 02/28/2013       
    FileDescription:  rse
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright © 1996-2013 Autodesk, Inc.
    LegalTrademarks:  Copyright © 1996-2013 Autodesk, Inc.
    Comments:         Copyright © 1996-2013 Autodesk, Inc.
```

Install the [latest Update](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/downloads/caas/downloads/content/update-4-for-inventor-2014-service-pack-2.html?v=2014) and look if this fixes it.

Also run [this .reg file](http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg) to disable dump creation and app verifier.